# Node JS, React JS, using Fetch API to POST image as Form Data *500 error*

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, fetch-api

I am new to node js. I am trying to send an image uploaded by the user to be stored in my backend using express js, but I keep getting a 500 error. What am I missing?

This is my front end code:

```
const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("myImage",this.state.fotoSelected);
        fetch("http://localhost:9000/producto", {
            method: 'post',
            body: formData,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
        })
            .then(response => {
                return response
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
            .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
    }
```

And this is the backend

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({
  limits:{fileSize: 1000000},
}).single("myImage");

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
      iconsole.log("Request ---", req.body);
      console.log("Request file ---", req.file)
      if(!err) {
          return res.send(200).end();
      }
  })
})
```

Comment: `iconsole.log("Request ---", req.body);` Typo at `i`?

Comment: i think that the 500 error is being raised by what @Phix mentionned

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `fetch` a `FormData` object it will generate a suitable Content-Type header automatically.

You are overriding that with `'multipart/form-data'` which is missing the **mandatory** `boundry` attribute. **Don't do that**.

Comment: Been tearing my hear out trying to get this to work. This did solve my problem. Also, I had to make sure that the exact objects were being added to the FormData and there were no extra commas in the body. You have to pay attention to all the details.